# Skrollr pages/slide beneath fires up and stays on top of current slide on screen but opacity is set to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, skrollr

My links don't work when the page/slide under the current slide on the screen is already on top of it, just invisible.

```
<section class="slide1">
   <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
</section>
<section class="slide2">Already on top of slide one, just invisible, so you won't be able to click that link.
</section>
```

Things is I can easily fix it by aligning my link to the right, but I just prefer it to be in the middle. I tried z-index on slide1 and slide2. I don't want to mess with the _main.js if it can be fixed with css.

EDIT: Just forgot to try position relative...AGHHH how could I forget. All good now.

Comment: Would it be possible to fix an example of this into a fiddle?

Comment: wrxsti - Sorry man, just forgot to try position:relative; GAH so stupid. Everything's good now.

Comment: Nice, you should put that in as an answer and accept it for anyone who has a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Tried position relative. Worked